# Add image links

Tags: xml, database, image, xml-parsing, phpmyadmin

I want to add image links in XML.

I'm working on [a project where I need to connect biological pathways](http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?scale=1.0&query=TLX&map=hsadd05202&scale=1.0&image=/share/www/mark_pathway136047628530435/hsadd05202.png&auto_image=&show_description=hide&multi_query=). The source is in the above URL when I tried to link up same as it is. But the links are not showing up when I hover over specific text. The website is also providing XML data. I don't know how to insert markup with the image.

I'm using PhpMyadmin for database development.

Comment: Looking at the page source, you can see it's done using `<map>` and `<area>`. Where is the XML you talk of?